# Defining a spatiotemporal (time-varying) kernel using GaussianProcessRegressor

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, gaussian-process

*(I edit the question to make it more specific and clear)*

### High-level idea

I want to implement the idea of capturing the correlation between two data points $x$ and $x'$ that can be different at two different time stamps $t$ and $t+1$, using `kernel` of `GaussianProcessRegressor`. I could use a kernel to capture the correlation between $x$ and $x'$. Nevertheless, there is the case that I have an external procedure that changes with time and affects the correlation of any two points. So at time $t$, maybe the two data points $x$ and $x'$ are highly correlated, but at $t+1$, the two data points are less correlated.

### Some maths

More precisely, I want to write in code a kernel $\tilde{K}$, s.t.:
$$\tilde{K}_t = K_t \circ D_t$$

where

- $x_t$ is the point selected at time $t$ ;
- $K_t = [k(x, x')]_{x, x' \in X_t}$ ;
- $D_t = [(1-\epsilon)^{|i-j|/2}]_{i, j=1}^t$, with $\epsilon$ being just a constant;
- $\circ$ is the Hadamarad product.

**Source:** This idea comes from the paper [arxiv.org/pdf/1601.06650.pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.06650.pdf), see eq. (7) and eq. (8).

Comment: Kernel's used to construct part of covariance matrix using training time-series. This describes the variability along temporal evolution of the variables, i.e., process. So, Kernels are spatio-temporal by definition, not sure what would be new if we add time-step values explicitly. Maybe time-scale information, but that can also be provided with Kernel hyper-parameters.

Comment: @msuzen Thank you very much for your reply. I can provide an example to make my point clearer. Let's say I want to capture the correlation between two data points `x` and `x'`. I could then use, let's say, a Matern kernel. Nevertheless, there is the case that I have an external procedure that changes with time and affects the correlation of any two points. So at time `t`, maybe the two data points `x` and `x'` are highly correlated, but during `t+1`, the two data points are less correlated. Does this make sense to you?How could I implement this?

Comment: Sounds like you would need to just apply lagged before computing the Kernel, such as, $k(L_{+1} x, x')$. Linear combination of such kernels maybe.

Comment: @msuzen I am not sure what exactly you mean by applying lag, but if I understand correctly, applying lag on `x` and `x'` and transforming them to `lag*x` and `lag*x'` might be problematic, because you change the two points per se, right? So in the beginning, we had `k(x, x')` and then, we have `k(lag*x, lag*x'`). 
What I want to do is write in python code the covariance `K_tilde` from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.06650.pdf , see eq. (7) and eq. (8) in the paper.

Comment: Nice paper, mean and covariance is time varying, there is no lag operation. See $D_{t}$ after Eq (3), it essentially takes care of the lagging. PS: Please add the paper in the original question.

Comment: @msuzen I agree the term $D_t$ is responsible for the lagging that we mention. My problem is how can this time-varying covariance be written in python, using GaussianProcessRegressor.